# How can a preloader dynamically determine target URL when served from CDN

Tags: actionscript-3, cdn, preloader

I have a preloader that is being served from a CDN, and I want it to load the target SWF also from the CDN but when it uses `loaderInfo`, it returns the hostname of the html file... Here's the setup:

- index.html (hosted on primary domain) uses SWFObject to embed preloader
- preloader.as hosted on remote CDN, contains code below
- target.swf is to be loaded

I have inherited this code from another developer that I can't contact and I'm not an AS coder...

```
var url:String = "target.swf"; 
....
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);   
loader = new Loader();      
loader.load(request);
```

This is what I've tried, but I think it's returning the url of the index.html, not the CDN-hosted preloader:

```
var currentUrl:String = stage.loaderInfo.url; 
var url:String = currentUrl.substring(0,currentUrl.length-13) + "target.swf";
....
```

Is there some way that I can get the URL that the preloader was served from which is the CDN?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stage.loaderInfo.url` returns indeed the URL of the page displaying the swf. You may give your swf the address of the CDN as a parameter:

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {CDNroot:'http://mycdn/'
    };
    var params = { 
        menu: "false",
        scale: "showAll",
        allowFullscreen: "true",
        allowScriptAccess: "always",
        quality:"best",
        bgcolor: "#FFFFFF"
    };
    var attributes = {
        id:"main", name:"main"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("loader.swf", "altContent", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```

Then to retrieve this parameter, use:

AS3

```
var url:String = stage.loaderInfo.parameters["CDNroot"] + "target.swf";
```